# How many fuel pumps does a Katana DA20 have?

Tags: aircraft-systems, piston-engine

How many fuel pumps does a [Diamond DA20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_DA20) have? And since the fuel pump sends fuel to the engine, if you turn it off after the takeoff as the check list says, how will the fuel reach the engine?

Comment: How on earth did this get onto the hot network questions list?

Comment: it contains good informations :)

Comment: Sure; it's just the sort of specialized, technical question that I wouldn't imagine many people would be interested in.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are 2 fuel pumps on the Diamond DA20. One is electric and is controlled by the pilot and one is mechanically driven by the engine and is constantly running while the engine is running.

After take off, you switch the electric one off and the mechanical one keeps supplying the engine with fuel.

[image]